# VHDL shift operators

Tags: vhdl

Hi I have the program below that does what I want to do, shift 1 bit left or right depending on inputs s_right or s_enable. The numeric.std library contains shift operators and I want to start using them so I get a better grasp on the language but can find no good examples that show me the right way at using them

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.all;


ENTITY  S_REG8 IS
port ( clk, s_enable, s_right, ser_in   :   in std_logic;
         ser_out                                :   out std_logic
        );
END ENTITY S_REG8;

ARCHITECTURE dflow OF S_REG8 IS
SIGNAL reg : std_logic_vector (7 DOWNTO 0); --7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0
SIGNAL selectors : std_logic_vector (1 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
SHIFT_REG:PROCESS (clk, s_enable, s_right)
    BEGIN
    selectors <= s_enable & s_right;
        IF clk'EVENT and clk ='1' THEN
            IF selectors <= "00" THEN
                reg (7 DOWNTO 0) <= reg (7 DOWNTO 0);
            ELSIF selectors <= "01" THEN
                reg (7 DOWNTO 0) <= reg (7 DOWNTO 0);
            ELSIF selectors <="10" THEN
                reg (0) <= ser_in;
                ser_out <= reg(7);
                --reg <= std_logic_vector(shift_left(unsigned(reg), 1);
                --SHIFT_LEFT (ARG: UNSIGNED; COUNT: NATURAL)
                reg (7 DOWNTO 1) <= reg (6 DOWNTO 0);

            ELSIF selectors <= "11" THEN
                reg (7) <= ser_in;
                ser_out <= reg(0);
                --reg <= shift_right(std_logic_vector(reg));
                reg (6 DOWNTO 0) <= reg (7 DOWNTO 1);                       
            END IF;
        END IF;
END PROCESS;
END ARCHITECTURE dflow;
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Actually shift_left and shift_right are functions not operators. Your assignment to selectors should be a concurrent signal assignment (outside the process) and the sensitivity list should have s_enable and s_right removed. There's a ser_out flip flop. Why are you using an ordering operator "<=" instead of equalifty operator "=" when evaluating selectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From package numeric_std, the body:

```
  -- Id: S.1
  function SHIFT_LEFT (ARG: UNSIGNED; COUNT: NATURAL) return UNSIGNED is
  begin
    if (ARG'LENGTH < 1) then return NAU;
    end if;
    return UNSIGNED(XSLL(STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(ARG), COUNT));
  end SHIFT_LEFT;

  -- Id: S.2
  function SHIFT_RIGHT (ARG: UNSIGNED; COUNT: NATURAL) return UNSIGNED is
  begin
    if (ARG'LENGTH < 1) then return NAU;
    end if;
    return UNSIGNED(XSRL(STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(ARG), COUNT));
  end SHIFT_RIGHT;
```

These call:

```
  -----------------Local Subprograms - shift/rotate ops-------------------------

  function XSLL (ARG: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR; COUNT: NATURAL) return STD_LOGIC_VECTOR
      is
    constant ARG_L: INTEGER := ARG'LENGTH-1;
    alias XARG: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(ARG_L downto 0) is ARG;
    variable RESULT: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(ARG_L downto 0) := (others => '0');   begin
    if COUNT <= ARG_L then
      RESULT(ARG_L downto COUNT) := XARG(ARG_L-COUNT downto 0);
    end if;


    return RESULT;   end XSLL;

  function XSRL (ARG: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR; COUNT: NATURAL) return STD_LOGIC_VECTOR
      is
    constant ARG_L: INTEGER := ARG'LENGTH-1;
    alias XARG: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(ARG_L downto 0) is ARG;
    variable RESULT: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(ARG_L downto 0) := (others => '0');   begin
    if COUNT <= ARG_L then
      RESULT(ARG_L-COUNT downto 0) := XARG(ARG_L downto COUNT);
    end if;
    return RESULT;   end XSRL;
```

Where you find SHIFT_LEFT fills `reg(0)` with '0'  and SHIFT_RIGHT fills `reg(7)` with '0'.

You had previously assigned `ser_in` to `reg(7)` and `reg(0)` respectively, those assignments would be lost (the last assignment in a sequence of statements wins).

So reverse the order of the assignments:

```
architecture fie of s_reg8 is
    signal reg:         std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    signal selectors:   std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
begin

    -- make process purely clock synchrnous
    selectors <= s_enable & s_right;
    -- ser_out multiplexer instead of flip flop:
    ser_out <=  reg(7) when s_right =  '0' else
                reg(0); --  when s_right = '1' else
                -- 'X';
shift_reg:
    process (clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge (clk) then -- immunity to metastability transitions
        -- if clk'event and clk ='1' then
            -- if selectors <= "00" then  -- redundant
            --     reg (7 downto 0) <= reg (7 downto 0);
            -- if selectors <= "01" then  -- redundant 
            --    reg (7 downto 0) <= reg (7 downto 0);
            -- elsif selectors <= "10" then
            if selectors = "10" then -- was elsif equality not 
                reg <= std_logic_vector(shift_left(unsigned(reg), 1));
                -- also added missing right paren
                reg (0) <= ser_in;  -- change the order so this occurs
                -- ser_out <= reg(7); -- no flip flop
                -- reg <= std_logic_vector(shift_left(unsigned(reg), 1); 
                -- SHIFT_LEFT (ARG: UNSIGNED; COUNT: NATURAL)
                -- reg (7 downto 1) <= reg (6 downto 0);

            -- elsif selectors <= "11" then
            elsif selectors = "11" then
                reg <= std_logic_vector(shift_right(unsigned(reg),1)); 
                -- missing distance, proper type conversion
                reg (7) <= ser_in;  -- change order so this assignment happens
                -- ser_out <= reg(0); -- no flip flop
                -- reg <= shift_right(std_logic_vector(reg));
                -- reg (6 downto 0) <= reg (7 downto 1);                       
            end if;
        end if;
end process;
end architecture;
```

Notice this also gets rid of the `ser_out` flip flop using a 2:1 mux instead, get's rid of the superfluous 'hold' assignments to `reg(7 downto 0)`, uses the rising_edge function for immunity to events from a metastability value on `clk` and moves the `selectors` assignment to a concurrent signal assignment, allowing the process to be purely clock synchronous.

With a testbench (for shift right only):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity s_reg8_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of s_reg8_tb is
    signal clk:             std_logic := '0';
    signal s_enable:        std_logic;
    signal s_right:         std_logic;
    signal ser_in:          std_logic;
    signal ser_out:         std_logic;
    constant ser_in_val0:   std_logic_vector (1 to 8) := x"B9";
    constant ser_in_val1:   std_logic_vector (1 to 8) := x"AC";
begin
    CLOCK: -- clock period 20 ns
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 800 ns then -- automagically stop the clock
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
DUT:
    entity work.s_reg8
        port map (
            clk => clk, 
            s_enable => s_enable, 
            s_right => s_right, 
            ser_in => ser_in,
            ser_out => ser_out
        );
STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        s_enable <= '1';
        s_right <= '1';
        for i in 1 to 8 loop
            ser_in  <= ser_in_val0(i);
            wait for 20 ns; -- one clock period
        end loop;
        for i in 1 to 8 loop
            ser_in  <= ser_in_val1(i);
            wait for 20 ns; -- one clock period
        end loop;   
        for i in 1 to 8 loop  -- so we get all val0 out
            ser_in  <= ser_in_val0(i);
            wait for 20 ns; -- one clock period
        end loop;   
        s_enable <= '0';
        wait for 20 ns;  -- one clock
        wait;      
    end process;
end architecture;
```

We get:
[image: s_reg8_tb.png]

Notice at this point we haven't tested s_enable nor s_right = '0', but SHIFT_RIGHT works. Will SHIFT_LEFT work?

The secret was assigning the serial in to reg(0) or reg(7) after the shift function.

Comment: Thank you for the great feedback, I've updated my code as per the points you made in your first comments regarding incorrect use of the ordering operator, made the selector assignment concurrent to the signal declaration and removed the s_enable and s_right from the sensitivity list. I will continue tomorrow or tonight hopefully. Again Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the detailed reply user1155120. I have used the description below to simulate the left and right shift of one bit through the register.

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.all;
ENTITY  S_REG8 IS
port ( clk, s_enable, s_right, ser_in   :   in std_logic;
         ser_out                                :   out std_logic
        );
END ENTITY S_REG8;
ARCHITECTURE dflow OF S_REG8 IS
SIGNAL reg:         std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
SIGNAL selectors:   std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
BEGIN
selectors <=  s_right & s_enable;
ser_out <=  reg(7) when selectors = "01" else
            reg(0); 
shift_reg:
PROCESS (clk)
BEGIN
    IF rising_edge (clk) THEN
        IF selectors = "01" THEN
            reg <= std_logic_vector(shift_left(unsigned(reg), 1));
            reg (0) <= ser_in;
            --  ser_out <= reg (7); 
        ELSIF selectors = "11" THEN
            reg <= std_logic_vector(shift_right(unsigned(reg),1)); 
            reg (7) <= ser_in; 
            --  ser_out <= reg (0);
        END IF;
    END IF;
END PROCESS;
END ARCHITECTURE;
```

For simulation I have been using Quartus II ModSim which I get the following results from:

[image: ModSim Results]

The results look great. Adding a single 1 bit state into the register I can see it move to the left or right of the register depending on the toggling of inputs s_right or s_enable.
The use of the multiplexer on the set_out and reg(0) and (7) makes much more sense in comparison to the addition latch that I added to the original description.
MANY THANKS